# How to save the elements of a list individually in R?

Tags: r, list, for-loop, element

So I've got a pretty long list of elements, and I want to save each of these elements individually as a dataframe. Right, now I'm trying to do so by:

```
for (i in 1:length(mylist)) {
  save.dta13(mylist[i], file=paste0(names(mylist)[i], ".dta"))
}
```

But that doesn't seem to be working, any ideas?

Comment: You probably want to use `[[` in `mylist[[i]]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `lapply` to loop over the `names` of the `list`

```
lapply(names(mylist), function(nm)
     save.dta13(mylist[[nm]], paste0(nm, ".dta")))
```

Comment: It doesn't give an error but nothing happens, what am I missing?

Comment: @Floris From which package `save.dta13` comes from?

Comment: @Floris I forgot a closing bracket.  Otherwise, it is working for me.  Have you checked your working directory for the files.

Comment: I noticed the bracket, however, when I run the script it just doesn't create any files...

Comment: @Floris I created the `mylist <- list(data.frame(v1 = 1:5), data.frame(vN = 1:7))` and it is working.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution (slightly different from what akrun has posted )

```
#An example list

L=list(mat1=matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),3,3),mat2=matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),3,3),mat3=matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),3,3))

#Convert elements of list to a data frame
L_DF = lapply(L,function(x)as.data.frame(x))

#Check the class of each element 
 class(L_DF$mat1)
#[1] "data.frame"



  class(L_DF$mat2)
#[1] "data.frame"


     class(L_DF$mat3)
#[1] "data.frame"


   names(L_DF)
#[1] "mat1" "mat2" "mat3"



#Save as dta

lapply(names(L_DF), function(x) {
     f <- L_DF[[x]]
     save(f, file=paste0(getwd(),'/', x, '.dta'))
 })
```