# How to loop through multiple variables and filter data to produce multiple dataframes?

Tags: python, r, dataframe, for-loop, while-loop

I have a dataframe df with about 1000 rows with the following columns:

```
df$ID<- c("ab11", "ab12" ...) #about 1000 rows
df$ID1<-numbers ranging from 1 to 20k # for all intense and purposes this can be treated as class 'factor'
df$Acol<- #numbers ranging from 1 to 1000
df$Bcol<- #numbers ranging from 0 to 1
```

The following lists gives me 12 values in each list:

```
A<- seq(50,600,by=50)
B<- seq(0.2,1,by=0.75)
```

I am trying to do 2 things:

1. I would like to create dataframes by filtering the original dataset with various combinations of lists A and B. So 144 dataframes.
2. Once I have those dataframes I would like to combine 3 dataframes at a time and see if the frequency of the IDs match a master dataframe x and if they do, get the combinations information for the matching dataframe.

So for 1, this is my approach:

```
df_50_0.2<-subset(df, df$Acol>=50 & df$Bcol>=0.2)
```

I can't write that out 144 times- I need a loop. I tried nested loop but that doesn't give me every combination of A and B so I tried a while loop.

Here is my code:

```
i<-50
while (i<550) {
   for (j in B) {
      assign(paste("df","_",as.character(i),"_",as.character(j)), df %>% 
      filter (Acol>=i) %>% 
      filter(Bcol>=j),envir=.GlobalEnv
   i<-i+50
  }}
```

That give me the desired result except it doesn't split the dataframe according to B. So the output is similar to what I would have if I had just filtered the data with values of A.

For the second part I need to loop through all possible combinations of three data frames at a time. Here is my code:

```
df.final<-rbind (df_50_0.2,df_100_0.25,df_150_0.5)
tmp<-subset(table(df.final$ID),!(table(df.final$ID) %in% table(x$ID))
```

I would like the above to be in a loop. If tmp has any values, I don't want it to be an output. If it is 0, that is, it is a perfect match to the frequency of IDs in the master dataframe x, I want that to be written. So something like the following in a loop? I want all possible combinations checked iteratively to come up with the combinations that match the master dataframe x ID frequency perfectly:

```
if tmp = NULL
tmp
else rm(tmp)
```

Any help is much appreciated. A python solution is also welcome!

A solution available in the following link but modified for two columns could be helpful [Filter loop to create multiple data frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54679034/filter-loop-to-create-multiple-data-frames)

Comment: Could you provide a minimal reproducible example? Try to make a toy example that would help us understand what you want to do.

Comment: Are you trying to create overlapping data frames? The command `df_50_0.2<-subset(df, df$A>=50 & df$B>=0.2)` will include all of the observations. The next one would include all but the ones in both of the smaller groups of A and B and so on.

Comment: @dcarlson, Yes. The data frames will be overlapping

Comment: @JoaoPedroMacalos, A solution available in the following link but modified for two columns could be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54679034/filter-loop-to-create-multiple-data-frames

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer, but it represents a different way to think about your problem. First we need a reproducible sample. I'm leaving out your first two columns, but it would not be difficult to modify the example to include them.

```
set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame(A=runif(200) * 1000 + 1, B=runif(200))
Aint <- seq(50, 600, by=50)
Bint <- seq(0.2, 1, by=0.05)
comb <- expand.grid(Aint=Aint, Bint=Bint)
```

This gives you a data frame of 200 observations and columns A and B. Then we create the intervals (called `Aint` and `Bint` so we don't confuse them with `df$A` and `df$B`. The next line creates all possible combinations of those intervals - 204 (not 144 since `Bint` has 17 values).

Now we need to define your groups and generate the label for each one:

```
groups <- apply(comb, 1, function(x)   df$A > x[1] & df$B > x[2])
labels <- paste("df", comb[, 1], comb[, 2], sep="_")
```

`groups` is a logical matrix 200 x 204 so each column defines one of your comparisons. The
first group is defined as `df[groups[, 1], ]` and the second as `df[groups[, 2], ]`. The labels for those comparisons are `labels[1]` and `labels[2]`.

Since your groups are overlapping, the next step will create multiple copies of your data in each group of three. The number of combinations of 204 groups taken 3 at a time is 1,394,204. The following generates the code to create the different combinations of 3 data frames:

```
allcombos <- combn(204, 3, simplify=TRUE)
for (i in 1:5) {
    dfno <- allcombos[, i]
    df.final <- rbind(df[groups[, dfno[1]], ], df[groups[, dfno[2]], ], df[groups[, dfno[3]], ])
    lbl <- labels[dfno]
    
}
```

The next step involves `subset(table(df.final$ID),!(table(df.final$ID) %in% table(x$ID))` but that line does not do what you suggest. It creates a frequency table of the number of times each ID appears in `df.final` and a table for a master data frame `x`. The %in% statement processes each frequency in `df.final` and checks to see if it matches the frequency of *ANY* ID in master. So I have not included that logical statement or code that would write the current `df.final` to a list.

Comment: This is a very good approach - no need to duplicate the data and clutter the workspace.

Comment: Thank you @dcarlson. This is powerful. Not sure how to proceed from here. I want to do df.final<-rbind(df[groups[, 1], ],df[groups[, 2], ],df[groups[, 3], ]) tmp<-subset(table(df.final$ID),!(table(df.final$ID) %in% table(x$ID)) if tmp = NULL
tmp
else rm(tmp) but iteratively for all possible combinations of 3 datasets.

Comment: @dcarlson, I also modified my original question in hopes of providing clarity for the second part

Comment: @dcarlson, Thanks again. What is allcombos in your for loop? So I am indeed trying to create a frequency table of the number of times each ID appears in df.final and a table for a master data frame x. Then using %in% statement process each frequency in df.final and check to see if it matches the frequency of ANY ID in master. If there is a complete match, (that is if i save it to tmp and tmp is empty), I would like to write out tmp. If they don't match I want tmp to be deleted.

Comment: @dcarlson,

if ‘groups’ that you created had 4 columns, I would do:

df.final<-rbind(df[groups[, 1], ],df[groups[, 2], ],df[groups[, 3], ])
tmp<-subset(table(df.final$ID),!(table(df.final$ID) %in% table(x$ID))
tmp
if tmp was empty, I will note this combination. if it had values that is, there were mismatches, i would delete tmp.
rm(tmp)

df.final<-rbind(df[groups[, 2], ],df[groups[, 3], ],df[groups[, 4], ])
tmp<-subset(table(df.final$ID),!(table(df.final$ID) %in% table(x$ID))
tmp
rm(tmp)

Comment: @dcarlson, putting it in two comments. too long for one.
df.final<-rbind(df[groups[, 1], ],df[groups[, 2], ],df[groups[, 4], ])
tmp<-subset(table(df.final$ID),!(table(df.final$ID) %in% table(x$ID))
tmp
rm(tmp)
df.final<-rbind(df[groups[, 1], ],df[groups[, 3], ],df[groups[, 4], ])
tmp<-subset(table(df.final$ID),!(table(df.final$ID) %in% table(x$ID))
tmp
rm(tmp)
so how do I write a loop to not write this steps manually

Comment: I've added the missing line that defines `allcombos`. Your other comments/questions are too hard to follow without formatting. Edit your original question to show this code and your questions.